# Syntax Errors when using ScaleDrawable()

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, custom-controls

I'm getting syntax errors when using ScaleDrawable(). I must be doing something wrong.
Any ideas?

2 errors I can't quite fix.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
protected class testbuttonBackgroundDrawable extends LayerDrawable {
/** my aim - the image used as background for the custom view is increased in
 *size by 25percent and then a yellow color filter is attached to it.
 *This yellow image then has the original background image layered on top of it
 *to create the effect of the image having a glow around it
 *I want to use this later on for when the custom button has focus
 */     
    ColorFilter colourFilter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, 1);

    ScaleDrawable resizedImage = new ScaleDrawable(background, 0, 1.25f, 1.25f);*
```

*error here is - Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

```
    nD = resizedImage.getDrawable();
    nD.setColorFilter(colourFilter);

    Drawable[] aD = new Drawable[2];
    aD[0] = nD;
    aD[1] = background;
    LayerDrawable _highlightedDrawable = new LayerDrawable(aD);

//This will make the background image fade if the button is set to disabled
    protected int _disabledAlpha = 100;
/**This is another scale drawable, this time used to shrink the background image of
 *the custom button when it is pressed
 */
    protected ScaleDrawable _pressedDrawable = new ScaleDrawable(background, 0, 0.75f, 0.75f);*
```

*error here is - "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block"

```
    public testbuttonBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) {
          super(new Drawable[] { d });
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] states) {
      boolean enabled = false;
      boolean highlighted = false;
      boolean pressed = false;

      for (int state : states) {
        if (state == android.R.attr.state_enabled)
            enabled = true;
        else if (state == android.R.attr.state_selected)
            highlighted = true;
        else if (state == android.R.attr.state_pressed)
            pressed = true;
      }

      mutate();
      if (enabled && highlighted) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(_highlightedDrawable); // buttons need transparent backgrounds
      } else if (!enabled) {
        setColorFilter(null);
        setAlpha(_disabledAlpha);
      } else if (enabled && pressed){
        setBackgroundDrawable(_pressedDrawable);
      } else {
        setColorFilter(null);
      }

      invalidateSelf();

      return super.onStateChange(states);
    }

}

}
```

Any help with fixing the errors would be appreciated.

I think I'm not using the ScaleDrawable constructor properly.

How do I do this correctly?

If that's not the problem then any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed it!

The problem was that I was doing my calculations for my button states in the wrong section of the layer drawable class. This is it fixed:

```
protected class CustomImageButtonBackgroundDrawable extends LayerDrawable { 

    protected Drawable lowerlayer;
    protected Drawable _highlightedDrawable;

    protected int _disabledAlpha = 100;
    protected Drawable _pressedDrawable;


    public CustomImageButtonBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d) {
          super(new Drawable[] { d });
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onStateChange(int[] states) {
      boolean enabled = false;
      boolean highlighted = false;
      boolean pressed = false;

      for (int state : states) {
        if (state == android.R.attr.state_enabled)
            enabled = true;
        else if (state == android.R.attr.state_selected)
            highlighted = true;
        else if (state == android.R.attr.state_pressed)
            pressed = true;
      }

      mutate();
      if (enabled && highlighted) {
        ColorFilter colourFilter = new LightingColorFilter(Color.YELLOW, 1);
        ScaleDrawable resizedImage = new ScaleDrawable(background, 0, 1.25f, 1.25f);

        lowerlayer = resizedImage.getDrawable();
        lowerlayer.setColorFilter(colourFilter);

        Drawable[] aD = new Drawable[2];
        aD[0] = lowerlayer;
        aD[1] = background;
        LayerDrawable _highlightedDrawable = new LayerDrawable(aD);

        setBackgroundDrawable(_highlightedDrawable); // buttons need transparent backgrounds

      } else if (!enabled) {
        setColorFilter(null);
        setAlpha(_disabledAlpha);

      } else if (enabled && pressed){
        ScaleDrawable smaller = new ScaleDrawable(background, 0, 0.75f, 0.75f);

        setBackgroundDrawable(smaller.getDrawable());

      } else {
        setColorFilter(null);
      }

      invalidateSelf();

      return super.onStateChange(states);
    }

}
```